What an integral grid
$\int ln(x^\pi) \,dx$  @ $(-1,\pi)$
(4.03335, 3.80018)
(3.55573, 3.80018)
(2.71828, 3.55573)
(3.80018, 2.71828)
(2.71828, 4.25722)
(4.68249, 3.80018)
(4.88585, 3.55573)
(3.29721, 2.71828)

  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
0 | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
1 | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T |
2 | U | V | W | X | Y | Z |   |   |   |   |
3 | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j |
4 | k | l | m | n | o | p | q | r | s | t |
5 | u | v | w | x | y | z |   |   |   |   |
6 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |

key: questions/116162

For convenience here is the question 116162
